# Google Chat : Only first response card coming for all buttons from a widget

Tags: google-hangouts

I have deployed Google ChatBot. 
I've created the following widget with 3 buttons in it,

```
function testwidgetData()
{

var RESHEADER = {
  header: {
    title : 'ChatBot',
    subtitle : 'Test widget',
    imageUrl : 'https://sites.google.com/a/abc.jpg'
  }
  };
  var widgets = [
    {
      textParagraph: {
        text: '<b>Test widget</b>'
      }
      },
             {
                  "keyValue": {
                    "content": 'Input one',
                    "contentMultiline": true,
                    "button": {
                      "textButton": {
                        "text": "One",
                        "onClick": {
                          action: 
                          {
                            actionMethodName: 'testAction',
                            parameters: [{key: 'entities',value:  "one"}]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                   {
                  "keyValue": {
                    "content": 'Input Two',
                    "contentMultiline": true,
                    "button": {
                      "textButton": {
                        "text": "Two",
                        "onClick": {
                          action: 
                          {
                            actionMethodName: 'testAction2',
                            parameters: [{key: 'entities',value:  "Two"}]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                    {
                  "keyValue": {
                    "content": 'Input Third',
                    "contentMultiline": true,
                    "button": {
                      "textButton": {
                        "text": "Third",
                        "onClick": {
                          action: 
                          {
                            actionMethodName: 'testAction3',
                            parameters: [{key: 'entities',value:  "Third"}]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
    ];

   return {
        "actionResponse":{
          "type": "NEW_MESSAGE"
        },
        cards: [RESHEADER, {
          sections: [{
            widgets: widgets
          }]
        }]
      };
}
```

`testAction` methods is handled in `onCardClick` like below,

```
function onCardClick(event) {
if(event.action.actionMethodName === 'testAction')
  {
          return createUserInformationResponseWidget('Your selected option is : '+event.action.parameters[0].value);
  }
  else if(event.action.actionMethodName === 'testAction2')
  {
          return createUserInformationResponseWidget('Your selected option is2 : '+event.action.parameters[0].value);
  }
  else if(event.action.actionMethodName === 'testAction3')
  {
          return createUserInformationResponseWidget('Your selected option is3 : '+event.action.parameters[0].value);
  }
}
```

`createUserInformationResponseWidget` is as below

```
function createUserInformationResponseWidget(response)
{
  var RESHEADER = {
  header: {
    title : 'Chatbot',
    subtitle : 'Action Performed Successfully!!!',
    imageUrl : 'https://sites.google.com/right-png-1.png'
  }
  };

    var widgets = [{
      textParagraph: {
        text: '<b>'+response+'</b>'
      }
    }];

    return {
      cards: [RESHEADER, {
        sections: [{
          widgets: widgets
        }]
      }]
    };
}
```

**My question is:** On clicking action button, I am getting response message for the first clicked button only - other operations are performed without any success/failure response. If I am clicking 'Three' button first then getting response for 3, 'One' & 'Two' are not working, same vice versa for all buttons.

Comment: It looks to me that you are passing the same things to your buttons. Could you provide an image of your buttons and also share your ```turnOnAutoResponder``` please

Comment: Actually I am having different method names there, here I pasted a sample to give an idea. I will update that with `turnOnAutoResponder`

Comment: @albertovielma: I've updated my question as requested.

Answer (score 1):

When creating custom cards with buttons, which will handle a certain action, you have to define an `onCardClick(event)` function in this way, it will receive a callback when the user clicks a button.

The `event` passed to your function will be of type [`CARD_CLICKED`](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/cards-onclick#receiving_user_click_information),  it will contain the appropriate information to handle your user's click action. For example, if you have more than just one button, you have to use `action.actionMethodName` to identify what button was clicked and then call the function related to that action. This is an example code:

```js
/**
 * Responds to a CARD_CLICKED event triggered in Hangouts Chat.
 *
 * @param event the event object from Hangouts Chat
 * @return JSON-formatted response
 */
function onCardClick(event) {
  var message = "";
  var reason = event.action.parameters[0].value;
  if (event.action.actionMethodName == "testAction") {
    message = testFunction(reason);
  } else if (event.action.actionMethodName == "testAction2") {
   message = testFunction(reason);
  } else if (event.action.actionMethodName == "testAction3") {
    message = testFunction(reason);
  }
  return message;
}

function testFunction(reason) {
  return {
    "actionResponse": { "type": "NEW_MESSAGE" },
    "cards": [{
      "sections": [{
        "widgets": [{
          "textParagraph": { "text": "TEST" }
         },  {
               "buttons": [{
        "textButton": {
          "text": "Set vacation in Gmail",
          "onClick": {
            "action": {
              "actionMethodName": "testAction",
              "parameters": [{
                "key": "reason",
                "value": reason
              }]
            }
          }
        }
      }, {
        "textButton": {
          "text": "Block out day in Calendar",
          "onClick": {
            "action": {
              "actionMethodName": "testAction2",
                "parameters": [{
                  "key": "reason",
                  "value": reason
                }]
            }
          }
        }
      }, {
        "textButton": {
          "text": "TEST",
          "onClick": {
            "action": {
              "actionMethodName": "testAction3",
                "parameters": [{
                  "key": "reason",
                  "value": reason
                }]
            }
          }
        }
      }]
        }]
      }]
    }]
  };
}
```

If you want to send [an update or new message](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/cards-onclick#responding_to_clicks_with_a_new_or_updated_message). You have to specify it by setting the `actionResponse.type` as ***`UPDATE_MESSAGE`*** or ***`NEW_MESSAGE`*** in that way you will have a new widget generated.

### Docs

- This is a nice tutorial you should check: [Call in sick with a custom bot for Hangouts Chat](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/chat-apps-script/#0).
- This shows how to handle intective cards: [Creating interactive cards](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/cards-onclick#click_to_open_url).
- This is a code example that shows how to handle new messages that have widgets: [JavaScript example: Vote Bot](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/cards-onclick#javascript_example_vote_bot)

Comment: I have followed all these steps in exact same way. My issue is all actions defined in a function are happening properly (for all button), only response widget is not getting created  second time onwards. If I click second button first then getting a response for second button as well, here 1st & 3rd button's response is missed.

Comment: It's been working for me. Try doing those steps again in a new project without changing anything (because I noticed you at least added the ```applyInHRMS``` function and those ```intentParams``` parameters). If it works like that (It should because I already tested it), then add your own function without adding the ```intentParams``` parameters. If it works like that, add your own parameters. That will be a nice way to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: I've updated whole question with simple methods now. As suggested I have made changes, question is same, it is still not working.

Comment: I think now I understand what is your issue, I updated my answer with the code, an explanation and a new doc.

Comment: Nope, still the same issue. Passed `NEW_MESSAGE` `actionType` & other minor changes/

Comment: Can you share a video of what is happening to you?

Comment: Sure I will record and send

Comment: any hint from this video?

Comment: Watching the video I could get finally the idea of what you were meaning and yes, it is happening the same to me, although I am able to see logs by going to *View* -> *Executions* on my Apps Script project and it is actually entering in the ```onCardClick``` function. I recommend you to open an issue on [Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=327918&template=1026870), describe your problem with a lot of detail and share this Stack Overflow question to give the post more context.

Comment: Sure, yes function is getting executed successfully. The success widget is not coming back

Comment: @albertovielma I've spent days trying to figure out how to update a card, Thank you so much! I do have another issue, I updated the card with "UPDATE_MESSAGE" I would also like to post to the thread. Is this possible or do I need to send a POST request?